# How to determine if a solid fits inside a given box in O(N^2)?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I'm looking for an algorithm that will let me determine if a solid object can fit inside of a box (rectangular prism) with given dimensions. The solid may be rotated and translated to fit inside the box.

I already have a solution to this problem:

1. Calculate the minimum bounding box of the solid (known algorithm).
2. Determine if the minimum bounding box fits inside the other box (easy).

(EDIT: this is not a valid solution)

This works, but I am looking for a more efficient solution. The minimum bounding box algorithm runs in O(n^3) time where n is the number of vertices. I am hoping for an O(n^2) algorithm.

Note that instead of a "solid object" I may just as well be asking if the set of points which form the convex hull of the solid can fit inside the box.

Comment: How many vertices are we talking about, from a practical standpoint?

Comment: As many as would be found on a realistic model of a detailed object, so between 100 and 10,000.

Comment: Ok.  Well, many of those vertices are not going to be relevant.  Only the ones that are farthest from the center of the object are going to matter (none of the "inside" or "concave" vertices matter at all, only the convex ones), so I'd start by doing a search for only those vertices that are going to make a difference in your calculation.  To put it another way, you don't need very much detail just to see if the object will fit.

Comment: Is it more efficient to calculate a bounding sphere?  If so, could you use the bounding sphere as a first check vs. the shortest length of the box, so that your amortized performance is better than O(N^3)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Good point. Aside from ignoring points inside the convex hull it might be good to ignore points close to some center of the object.

Comment: @EricJ. I could easily find the minimum bounding sphere in O(N^2), but the minimum bounding sphere may not fit inside the box even when the solid will. Think of fitting a rod-like object inside a box by orienting it along the diagonal.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if the culling process got you down to around 100 relevant vertices in all cases, which would make your existing O(n^3) algorithm viable.

Comment: Wouldn't a [convex hull](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Convex_hull) which can be computed in O(n^2) substitute for the minimum bounding box which would resolve the problem?

Comment: @mikebolt: Yes, but if the minimum bounding sphere fits in, the minimum bounding box also will.  Only if it does not fit will you need the more expensive minimum bounding box calculation.  If a substantial amount of input data passes the bounding sphere calculation, you can avoid the bounding box calculation for a substantial fraction of input values (thus you will have an amortized performance somewhere between O(N^2) and O(N^3).

Comment: "Calculate the minimum bounding box of the solid (known algorithm)". Please, what is your 'known algorithm'?

Comment: I don't think that your solution is correct (by the way, you didn't say in what sense the bounding box is minimal). There could be suboptimal bounding boxes that fit in the box while the optimal one does not.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You're right. The algorithm I had in mind is O'Rourke's algorithm which finds the minimum volume bounding box. I'm thinking now that I can solve the problem by tweaking that algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at [this paper](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-06-winter/Slides/an_bounding_box_fall.pdf). It gives an algorithm than compute an 1+epsilon approximation of a 3D minimum bounding box in O(n log n + 1/epsilon^3) time.

Answer (score 0):

### Quickly ruling some objects out

If you expect the answer to usually be "No", you may be able to rule out many instances (fairly) quickly as follows: if there is a pair of points separated by more than the longest diagonal of your box, then the shape cannot possibly fit in it.  This is O(n^2), but you can stop as soon as you find a more distant pair, and you could also first sort points along the longest dimension and take points from opposite ends as your pairs to increase the chances of finding

Combined with Eric J.'s suggestion of using a bounding sphere to rule an object *in*, this might quickly solve many cases.

### Quickly ruling some objects in

Another option you have is to just randomly project the points a bunch of times, and calculate the AABB; if it fits inside your box, you're done.  This requires [generating random unit-length vectors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/random/uniform_on_sphere.hpp).

Answer (score 0):

If [this](http://geomalgorithms.com/a08-_containers.html) isn't outdated there is currently no faster exact algorithm:

> The current fastest 3D bounding cuboid algorithm is by [O'Rourke, 1985], which runs in O(n3) time, has several special cases, and is considerably more difficult to implement. O’Rourke’s algoruthm is based on his observation that “A box of minimal volume circumscribing a convex polyhedron must have at least two adjacent faces that contain edges of the polyhedron.” No faster exact algorithm has been found.
>
> Regardless, since O(n3) algorithms can be very slow in practice for large point sets, there is considerable interest in fast approximations for the minimum cuboid in 3D and higher dimensions. Several methods have been suggested, such as: (1) only consider cuboids that have a face coinciding with a polyhedron face (which is O(n2) as discussed in [O'Rourke, 1985], and can be 2 times too large), (2) principal component analysis on the point set (which is fast, but often results in a poor solution), (3) brute-force methods that sample many possible orientations for a cuboid, (4) reduce a large point set to a smaller approximate set (e.g., by selecting the cells in a discrete grid that contain set points) [Barequet & Har-Peled, 1999], and others. All these methods have trade-offs between the solution accuracy versus the efficiency of execution.

So you will have to decide if you need exact results, or if you can live with an approximation and use on of the referenced articles.